# Vue-3. Set component data model with unknown structure using option api

Tags: vuejs3

My child component should be created with data model that I get externally using fetch.
Structure of this model is not predetermined (kind of black box). Important thing is that I am working with detailed representation of some entity, not a list (array). I have few options how to do this, but I dont like any. Maybe there is better solution.

1. **Use `$data` property**.
   But vue [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#data) dont like this:

> Adding new properties to this.$data is possible, but it is not
> recommended

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                showDialog: false   // some predefined prop
            };
        },
        methods: {
            async fetch() {
                // fetch from external resource
            }
        },
        async created() {
            let model = await this.fetch();
            Object.assign(this.$data, model);
        }
    };
</script>
<template>
    <p>{{ Name }}</p> <!-- Name is part of model -->
</template>
```

2. **Set `model` property in advance**. This aproach hides all content of model. So in this case I have to use `this.model.Name` instead of `this.Name` ..

For example:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                model: {},
                showDialog: false
            };
        },
        methods: {
            async fetch() {
                // fetch from external resource
            }
        },
        async created() {
            let model = await this.fetch();
            Object.assign(this.$data.model, model);
        }
    };
</script>
<template>
    <p>{{ model.Name }}</p>
</template>
```

**3. Parent component provide model to child using `props`.** But I guess it is better when child is responsible for getting model and as a result holds all logic inside.

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['initialModel'],
        data() {
            let data = {
                showDialog: false
            };
            return Object.assign(data, this.initialModel);
        }
    };
</script>
<template>
    <p>{{ Name }}</p>  <!-- Name is part of model -->
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking what's the best solution, I would recommend using your second option where you bind all custom properties under **models** or whatever naming convention you have. This way it's more explicit which properties are dynamic and you can store and access all of them under a single property when you're working with them.

```
data() {
    return {
        models: {},
    }
},
async created() {
    this.models = await this.fetchData()
},
```

If you don't always want to access them from a parent property, you can destructure them from **models** when you're working with them.

```
const { property1, property2 } = this.models
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Any other solutions don't come to my mind. So maybe I will choose second option.